# How to specify a parameter value for Ninject bound object that is automatically injected into another object?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Disclaimer: I'm very new to Ninject and DI in general. Also, I'm not married to Ninject. If anyone wants to explain how this would work in Windsor, Unity, SourceMap, or something else, I'm all ears.

I've got the following class that handles storing objects of type `TArchived`:

```
public class Archiver<TArchived> where TArchived : class
{
    public Archiver(Func<string> getName, IStore<TArchived> storage, Func<TArchived> getInitialState);
}
```

When an instance of `Archiver` is created, it attempts to look up in `storage` an instance with the name returned from `getName()`. If there is no instance, it creates one with the default returned from `getInitialState()`.

The next class uses `Archiver` to store a list of items. However, while that list of items will never change in size, *that list is not known at compile-time*.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public class Item
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public MyClass(Archiver<Item[]> archiver)
    {
        Archiver = archiver;
    }

    public static Item[] GetInitialState(IEnumerable<string> values)
    {
        return values.Select(value => new Item { Value = value }).ToArray();
    }

    public Archiver<Item[]> Archiver { get; private set; }
}
```

I've set up Ninject like so:

```
public class Tests
{
    private IKernel Ninject { get; set; }

    public Tests()
    {
        Ninject = new StandardKernel();
        Ninject.Bind<IStore<MyClass.Item[]>>().To<MemoryStore<MyClass.Item[]>>();

        Ninject.Bind<Archiver<MyClass.Item[]>>().To<Archiver<MyClass.Item[]>>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("getName", new Func<string>(() => "TEST"))
            .WithConstructorArgument("getInitialState", new Func<MyClass.Item[]>(MyClass.GetInitialState(/* what here? */)));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        // testing options
        var tests = new[] { "A", "B" };

        var myClass = Ninject.Get<MyClass>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_2()
    {
        // different testing options
        var tests = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };

        var myClass = Ninject.Get<MyClass>();
    }
}
```

But I'm confused as to what to put for the `getInitialState` parameter. If I want different lists of items stored by `MyClass`, I need to pass different items in to the `GetInitialState` function.

Answer (score 1):

After some more experimentation, these are the best solutions I have come up with. I would love to see a better way.

```
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
    Ninject.Bind<Func<MyClass.Item[]>>().ToProvider<Func<MyClass.Item[]>>(new CallbackProvider<Func<MyClass.Item[]>>((ctx) => () => MyClass.GetInitialState(new[] { "A", "B" })));
    var myClass = Ninject.Get<MyClass>();
}

[Fact]
public void Test2()
{
    Ninject.Bind<Func<MyClass.Item[]>>().ToConstant<Func<MyClass.Item[]>>(() => MyClass.GetInitialState(new[] { "A", "B", "C" }));
    var myClass = Ninject.Get<MyClass>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pull a constructor argument out of the binding, and add it at the point of resolution.  So use this binding:

```
Ninject.Bind<Archiver<MyClass.Item[]>>().To<Archiver<MyClass.Item[]>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("getName", new Func<string>(() => "TEST"));
```

And then use this in each unit test, changing the value of *getInitialState* as needed:

```
var myClass = Ninject.Get<MyClass>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("getInitialState", 
        new Func<MyClass.Item[]>(MyClass.GetInitialState(new string[] { "1", "2", "3" }))
    );
```

Comment: This is the result I get: (note that I had to modify your code to use `new ConstructorArgument...`, since the result of `Get<MyClass>()` is an object of type `MyClass`).

Comment: `Exception
Ninject.ActivationException: Ninject.ActivationException : Error activating IntPtr
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
  4) Injection of dependency IntPtr into parameter method of constructor of type Func{Item[]}
  3) Injection of dependency Func{Item[]} into parameter buildInitialValue of constructor of type Archiver{Item[]}
  2) Injection of dependency Archiver{Item[]} into parameter archiver of constructor of type MyClass
  1) Request for MyClass`

Answer (score 0):

I havent delved into the depths of your question, but it sounds to me like you're looking for [Named Scopes](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki) or something very close to that as a way of managing things like this at a higher level. I recommend following the links from there to @Remo Gloor's blog posts on the topics (and adding any missing ones into [the NamedScope extension wiki](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki) :D).